# Open Source Database Cache Implementation in Java

Tags: database, caching, synchronization, nodes

I want to implement Open Source Database Cache which will be used by many nodes altogether.

Many nodes should retrieve and update that cache at a same time.

How can I implement that cache successfully and easily ?

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

It can be a rather involved exercise. Have you considered using open source project like our Cacheonix http://www.cacheonix.org? It has a distributed mode that runs on multiple nodes and supports concurrent retrieving and updating.

Comment: Thanks, I achieved it with ehCache.